# Children Canvas of 5.6

Tags: unity

After upgrading to Unity 5.6, I've found my children canvases don't render right. I'm trying to figure out if this is a bug, or a new feature in Unity 5.6 that needs some adjusting.

[image]

Note the grey block on the upper left. What should be shown is a minimap, but per best practices, I was told to take frequently updating UI elements and put them on their own canvases. To compare this, here is an example from last week. The most notable difference is the transparent vs opaque view on the left. I did that in order to try to fix the problem, but it was on my todo list anyways.

Is there some setting that I should do to make the children canvases look right?

[image]

Comment: Have you been using anything concerning image effects on the minimap? They seem to have replaced those (and maybe some other stuff as well): https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139861/unity-5-6-where-have-sun-shafts-disappeared-to/139884#139884

Comment: Not really. I think the minimap is just an image. I should also mention that if I delete the child canvas, it works without issues.