# Unity 5.6 - Where have Sun Shafts disappeared to?

Tags: unity

I've just upgraded to Unity 5.6 from 5.4. I need to add some Sun Shafts to my camera but I cannot find the script *anywhere*.

I've looked in the docs, I've looked in the menu's but I can't locate them.

Has anyone else had this problem at all?

Comment: Have you installed Standard Assets Effects package again after upgrading to 5.6? https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/HOWTO-InstallStandardAssets.html It also notes on the page that: "A newer version might make your project look or behave differently and you may need to re-tweak its parameters. Check the package contents and Unity’s release notes before you decide to re-install."

Comment: Yeah I've done a clean install, it's not there @JohnHamilton from what I can see. Can't find how I would add the Sun Shafts at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, this answer will be a bit short but I've found out what happened to your sun shafts and how you can get the new effects to replace them.

It seems [Image Effects](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/comp-ImageEffects.html) (which include [Sun Shafts](https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/Manual/script-SunShafts.html)) are no longer a thing in Unity's 5.6 version. They now have [post-processing](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html) instead and you can get the package for that from their [asset store link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/83912).

Comment: Awesome, cheers John, looks to be what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

The original SunShafts scripts can be found from unity's asset store(from their own page). It's titled "Legacy Image Effects".

Answer (score -1):

you will find then at the lights gameobject... after select yours look at the inspector.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm non the wiser, are you able to show screenshots?